# How can i resolve, that I get the permission dialog again and again?

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

Only at some devices I get the permission dialog again and again. If the user klicks on accept, the permission dialog comes again. If the user klicks on cancel, the permission dialog comes again.

onCreate:

```
checkwriteStoragePermission();
checkReadStoragePermission();
```

checkReadStoragePermission:

```
private void checkReadStoragePermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            DialogInterface.OnClickListener onClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE) {

                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Login.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, EXT_STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE);


                    } else if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE) {
                        onPermissionsNotGranted();

                    }
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    finish();
                    startActivity(getIntent());
                }
            };
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle(R.string.permissions_title)
                    .setMessage(R.string.permissions_message)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.btn_continue, onClickListener)
                    .setNegativeButton(R.string.btn_cancel, onClickListener)
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .show();
            return;
        }
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Login.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, EXT_STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE);
        return;
    }

}
```

checkwriteStoragePermission:

```
 private void checkwriteStoragePermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            DialogInterface.OnClickListener onClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE) {

                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Login.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                    } else if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE) {
                        onPermissionsNotGranted();
                    }
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            };
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle(R.string.permissions_title)
                    .setMessage(R.string.permissions_message)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.btn_continue, onClickListener)
                    .setNegativeButton(R.string.btn_cancel, onClickListener)
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .show();
            return;
        }
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Login.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        return;
    }

}
```

Comment: are you sure you get this , only on some devices ?

Comment: yes, I am sure. Only on some devices

Comment: What does onPermissionsNotGranted(); do ?

Also only devices from Marshmallow and above will show popup for permission requests

Comment: onPermissionsNotGranted(); do: gives a Toast() to the user that the permission granted